# using torrents to back up vhd's

Tags: linux, backup, vhd, utorrent

Hi it's a question and it may be redundant but I have a hunch there is a tool for this - or there should be and if there isn't I might just make it - or maybe I am barking up the wrong tree in which case correct my thinking:

But my problem is this: I am looking for some way to migrate large virtual disk drives off a server once a week via an internet connection of only moderate speed, in a solution that must be able to be throttled for bandwidth because the internet connection is always in use.

I thought about it and the problem is familar: large files that can moved that also be throttled that can easily survive disconnection/reconnection/large etc etc - the only solution I am familiar with that just does it perfectly is **torrents**.

Is there a way to automatically strategically make torrents and automatically "send" them to a client download list remotely? I am working in Windows Hyper-V Host but I use only Linux for the guests and I could easily cook up a guest to do the copying so consider it a windows or linux problem.

**PS: the vhds are "offline" copies of guest servers by the time I am moving them - consider them merely 20-30gig dum files.**

**PPS: I'd rather avoid spending money**

Answer (score 1):

Bittorrent is an excellent choice, as it handles both incremental updates and automatic resume after connection loss very well.

To create a .torrent file automatically, use the `btmakemetainfo` script found in the original bittorrent package, or one from the numerous rewrites (bittornado, ...) -- all that matters is that it's scriptable. You should take care to set the "disable DHT" flag in the .torrent file.

You will need to find a tracker that allows you to track files with arbitrary hashes (because you do not know these in advance); you can either use an existing open tracker, or set up your own, but you should take care to limit the client IP ranges appropriately.

This reduces the problem to transferring the .torrent files -- I usually use `rsync` via ssh from a cronjob for that.

Answer (score 0):

For point to point transfers, torrent is an expensive use of bandwidth. For 1:n transfers it is great as the distribution of load allows the client's upload bandwidth to be shared by other clients, so the bandwidth cost is amortised and everyone gains...

It sounds like you have only one client in which case I would look at a different solution...

[wget](http://go2linux.garron.me/limit_rate_resume_downloads_wget) allows for throttling and can resume transfers where it left off if the FTP/http server supports resuming transfers... That is what I would use

Comment: yes to be honest I was going to port block the torrent client from all but one IP to get around the "bandwidth noise" issue but I hear what you are saying about wget - I didn't know it was that extensible.. let me check it out and get back to you

Comment: Edited answer to add the link you want ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync for that (http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). Search for the --partial option in man and that should do the trick. When a transfer is interrupted the unfinished result (file or directory) is kept. <s>I am not 100% sure if it works with telnet/ssh transport **when you send from local to a remote location** (never checked that) but it should work with rsync daemon on the remote side.</s>
You can also use that for sync in two local storage locations.

```
rsync --partial [-r for directories] source destination
```

edit: Just confirmed the crossed out statement with ssh